# EM duality transformation

Tags: electromagnetism, duality

I have read that by defining a dual transformation as
$$
\begin{pmatrix} F'^{\mu \nu} \\ ^*F'^{\mu \nu} \end{pmatrix} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos (\alpha ) & \sin (\alpha ) \\ -\sin (\alpha ) & \cos (\alpha ) 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} F^{\mu \nu} \\ ^*F^{\mu \nu} \end{pmatrix}
$$

where
$$
F^{\mu \nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &  -E^x &  -E^y &  -E^z \\
  E^x & 0 & - B^z & B^y \\
  E^y & B^z & 0 & - B^x \\
  E^z & - B^y & B^x & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\quad \text{and} \quad
^*F^{\mu \nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &  -B^x &  -B^y &  -B^z \\
  B^x & 0 &  E^z & -E^y \\
  B^y & -E^z & 0 &  E^x \\
  B^z &  E^y & -E^x & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$

it is equivalent to say that $E$ and $B$ transform as
$$
\begin{pmatrix} E' \\ B' \end{pmatrix} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\cos (\alpha ) & \sin (\alpha ) \\ -\sin (\alpha ) & \cos (\alpha ) 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} E \\ B \end{pmatrix}.
$$

But how can I find it from the Faraday tensor? (replacing with $\mu$ and $\nu$ is a bad idea apparently)

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/318976/symmetry-in-electricity-and-magnetism-due-to-magnetic-monopoles/319036#319036). It might be helpful. Note that in the complex formulation the duality transformation appears as a unit phase.

Answer (score 2):

This follows immediately from the first equation that you wrote. Just fix a $\mu \nu$ and obtain that the corresponding component of the Electric/Magnetic field is given by what you wrote in the last equation.